# JSONify returning strange values

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, python-3.x

What I'm trying to do is return the result of a function in Python back to my javascript through AJAX. Currently I am getting [This Response](https://jsonformatter.org/488070) while I'm expecting "True" or "False"

jquery:

```
  var test = $.getJSON("/chk_chn", {
    name: channel_name
  });

  alert(test.toSource())
```

python:

```
@app.route("/chk_chn")
def chk_chn_unique():
"""Checks a name against all existing Channels in a Channel List. Returns True if name is unique, False otherwise"""
name = request.args.get("name")
for channel in Channels:
    if channel.get_name() == name:
        return jsonify(result=False)
return jsonify(result=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had several problems.

First, my Ajax query did not have any callback function. Thanks to Rawri for pointing that out. The code is now the following.

```
      $.getJSON("/chk_chn", { name: channel_name} )
  .done(function( json ) {
    console.log(json.result)
    // Check Name Uniqueness
    if (json.result === false) {
      $("#chn_name").after('<span class="error">Channel name already exists</span>');
    }
    else {
      // Check Channel Length
      if (channel_name.length > 20) {
        $("#chn_name").after('<span class="error">Channel Name exceeds maximum length</span>');
        return false
      }
      else {
        // Create Channel
        socket.emit("create_channel", {"channel_name": channel_name})
        // Close the modal
        return true;
      }
    }
  })
  .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
    var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
    console.log("Request Failed: " + err);
  });
```

My second and even more stupid issue was that the Ajax query was being called by a button that existed in a Modal. When the button was clicked, the Modal was closed and the javascript was regenerated on the new page, thus discarding my query entirely.

I fix this by returning false on my form

```
<form role="form" id="submit_channel" onsubmit="return false">
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
return jsonify({result: True})
```

Comment: I get back the exact same response

Answer (score 0):

You're missing your callback function and just printing out the request object.

Try this:

```
$.getJSON('/chk_chn', { name: channel_name })
    .done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```